# How to quickly snap a view in storyboard back into its constraints after accidentally moving it

Tags: xcode, storyboard, alignment, constraints, shortcut

Everything I have found, every one says this cant be done.

I studied in fullsail university and they taught me how to do this so I know without a doubt it *can* be done. No one just knows how and assumes it can't.

Basically, when in XCode-story board, I would add constraints to a view and everything is all blue and perfect. From there, if you click, hold a drag, the view to another position then all of the constraints will turn orange. (Not RED because the constraints are still good it just simply needs to snap back into place..)

When in school my teacher taught me a quick key short cut that you press and everything snaps back into place and its all blue again. It has been a while since I have coded and i am just now getting back into it again and i just cant remember what that shortcut was.

I hope someone out there knows how to do this. Maybe any fullsail graduates?

Your responses are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

option + CMND + '='

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is referred to as "Update(ing) Frames."

The quick command is indeed option-command-equals

The command can also be reached from the bottom menu of a storyboard.

[image: Apple storyboard commands]

This link may change in the future but check out the [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html). Specifically reference the "Resolve Auto Layout Issues Tool" section.